# Plugin Toggle Flashlight in react-native with expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, plugins, expo, flashlight

Im a search I found an old expo plugin, but it doesn't seem to work anymore. With ReactNative npx I was able to use it, but I would like to use it with expo, is there nothing to replace it to make only the flashlight work?

And can I make this flashlight be accessed with the application closed?

I tried to turn on the flashlight on the cell phone using expo, but the plugin seems to have been discontinued.